# How to properly override base class function in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, overriding

I have the following two structures, child inherits from base:

```
struct Base{
    double S1(int x){
        return x*x;
    }
    double S2(int x){
        return 2*x;
    }
    double S(int x){
        return S1(x) + S2(x);
    }
};


struct Child: Base{
    double S1(int x){
        return 0.0;
    }
    double S2(int x){
        return 0.0;
    }
};
```

`S(int x)` uses `S1(int x)` and `S2(int x)` to produce its result. I want to override `S1` and `S2` in the child, which seems to work. The following outputs:

```
Child child;
Base base;
std::cout<<child.S(2.0)<<std::endl;  //<-- 8   not OK, still base S
std::cout<<child.S1(2.0)<<std::endl; //<-- 0   OK, child S1
std::cout<<base.S1(2.0)<<std::endl;  //<-- 4   OK, base S1
std::cout<<base.S(2.0)<<std::endl;   //<-- 8   OK, base S
```

`8 0 4 8` which shows that `S1` was indeed overriden. However, `child.S` appears to call the base structure's `S` which, in turn uses the base's functions `S1` and `S2`. How can I make the child's `S` (which is not explicitly defined here as it is inherited) use the overriden `S1` and `S2`?

Comment: (1) You need the base method to be `virtual`, (2) You need to access them via a pointer/reference to base. Most important: You should consider using a proper C++ book: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make `S1` and `S2` virtual

```
struct Base{
    virtual double S1(int x){
        return x*x;
    }
    virtual double S2(int x){
        return 2*x;
    }
    double S(int x){
        return S1(x) + S2(x);
    }
};


struct Child: Base{
    double S1(int x){
        return 0.0;
    }
    double S2(int x){
        return 0.0;
    }
};
```

Comment: No, this is not enough. You need to access the methods via a pointer/refernce to base to invoke polymorphism. The OP did not do that.

Comment: @wohlstad No, you don't need to do that.

Comment: @wohlstad the above method seemed to work. I don't know about its limitations though.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I see now. It works because the call to `S1` and `S2` in `Base::S` is actually done via the `this` pointer so the OP gets the required result.

Comment: In that context, `return S1(x) + S2(x);` is equivalent to `return this->S1(x) + this->S2(x);` and it will use dynamic dispatch. It's a classic approach is one wants to mix non-virtual public interface with customisable virtual private methods.

Comment: @pptaszni yes I just realized that (see my comment above yours). However there is still a call via a pointer/reference here the OP should be aware of.